# justify center not in center position

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

i am creating a simple stepper component in vue. I have been able to achieve desired fucntionality but the alignment goes to left even after applying `justify-content: center`

below is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-sky-pj9p5x

```
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-center full-width" style="border: 1px">
    <div class="flex no-wrap justify-center full-width">
      <div
        class="flex full-width items-center q-pb-xl"
        v-for="steps in data"
        :key="steps.key"
      >
        <div
          class="stepper-circle"
          :class="{
            'stepper-circle--filled': currentStep === steps.key,
            'stepper-circle--unfilled': currentStep < steps.key,
          }"
        >
          <q-icon
            v-if="currentStep > steps.key"
            name="check"
            color="white"
            size="xs"
          />
          <div
            v-else
            class="stepper-circle__dot"
            :class="{
              'stepper-circle__dot--active': currentStep === steps.key,
            }"
          />
          <div
            class="stepper-circle__label"
            :class="{ 'text-grey fw3': currentStep < steps.key }"
          >
            {{ steps.name }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          :class="{
            'stepper-separator': steps.key < data.length,
            'stepper-separator--active': steps.key < currentStep,
          }"
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Stepper",

  data() {
    return {
      currentStep: 1,
      data: [
        {
          name: "Step 1",
          key: 1,
        },
        {
          name: "Step 2",
          key: 2,
        },
        {
          name: "Step 3",
          key: 3,
        },
      ],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    getSeparatorWidth(stepKey) {
      const totalSteps = this.data.length - 1;
      const widthPercentage = (100 / totalSteps) * stepKey;
      return widthPercentage;
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
.justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.stepper-separator {
  height: 2px;
  background: #d1d5db;
  transition: width 2s;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.stepper-separator--active {
  background: #08104d;
}

.stepper-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 2px solid #08104d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #08104d;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.stepper-circle__dot {
  background: #d1d5db !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.stepper-circle__dot--active {
  background: #08104d !important;
}

.stepper-circle__label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #08104d;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: flex;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.stepper-circle--filled {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  border: 2px solid #08104d !important;
}

.stepper-circle--unfilled {
  background: white !important;
  border: 2px solid #d1d5db !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: (Emphasis on the **minimal**; if you have a layout problem then the JavaScript and Vue templating is superfluous. Reduce it to straightforward HTML and CSS. It will be a more useful question that more people will be able to answer and learn from).

Answer (score 1):

You have to maximize last element's width, and to settle your concerns with the responsiveness, like so:

```
.flex.full-width.items-center.q-pb-xl:nth-child(3) {max-width: 36px;}
```

because otherwise it stretches out the content to the left.

Comment: Not sure it this will work for responsive layouts.

Comment: As I saw, it does work, you'll see too. The window is resizable.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To center the stepper, you can wrap the entire component in another `div` and apply `justify-content: center;` to that.

Example;

```
<template>
 <div class="flex justify-center full-width" style="border: 1px">
   <div class="flex justify-center">
     <div class="flex no-wrap justify-center full-width">
       <!-- Your existing code -->
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

But, if you want to center the stepper component vertically as well, you can use the `align-items: center;` property to aligns the flex items along the vertical line in the center of the container.

Example;

```
<template>
 <div class="flex justify-center items-center full-height" style="border: 1px">
   <div class="flex justify-center">
     <div class="flex no-wrap justify-center full-width">
       <!-- Your existing code -->
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Note that for `align-items: center;` to work, the parent of the flex container should have a height greater than the height of the flex container. Therefore, set the height to the maximum;

```
.full-height {
 height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use display:flex for the parent then use justify-content:center